# Choose Music from iPhone app? - iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

Can anyone give me a head starters on this question. How would I be able to make an app that searches through your music contents that  are already synced on your phone and play them. I don't want to do a scroll view, where the user just presses on the options. Instead I want the user to type the song name and if the song is found it will play it.

thanks,

kevin

Answer (score 2):

The class you are looking for is [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).  It's only available in iPhone 3.0 and above.

Get the instance for your app ([MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]) rather than the iPod instance.  You can use this to play the songs once you've located them.

In order to do your own search rather than presenting the typical interface check out  [MPMediaQuery](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

I found [this article](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/07/the-music-player-framework-in-the-iphone-sdk/) helpful.  It's mostly about iPod player integration, but it touches on these other topics too.